# How to use preg_match to match more than one variables?

Tags: php

I have a lot of variables that I want to validate with the same pattern, they look like this:

```
$pattern = "/[$()`]/"
$one
$two
$three
etc...
```

Instead of writing it like this:

```
if (!preg_match($pattern, $one) && !preg_match($pattern, $two) && !preg_match($pattern, $three)) {
// do stuff
}
```

Is there a simpler way of validating those variables all at once ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array= array($one, $two, $three);

if (in_array("$()`", $array))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
?>
```

I hope this will work for you

Comment: You can pass your all values in array and only one time you have check that in array if your pattern  in array condition will fulfill otherwise not. I hope you gets what i'm try to say.

Comment: But what If I want to use regex instead of just normal match ?

Comment: i was only implement this function in my carrier but give me some time i will r&d and give you the feed back.

Answer (score 0):

What about it:

```
$tests = array($one, $two, $three);
$tests_count = count($tests);

if (count(preg_grep('/[$()`]/', $tests, PREG_GREP_INVERT)) == $tests_count) {
    // some stuff
}
```

If you want to do some stuff if any of tests fails, it can be:

```
count(preg_grep('/[$()`]/', $tests, PREG_GREP_INVERT)) > 0)
```